# Select data from two different tables that dont have the same number of columns

Tags: sql

I've searched so many times a way to do what I want to do but can't find anything. I know I must use JOIN or UNION to do it but I'm new to SQL and have some difficulties to understand how it works exactly. The whole dependencies thing especially.

Here's my challenge, I got two tables (and many more) on my database, one called players and the other one called organizations.

I don't have the same number of columns in the two tables and no dependencies neither if I understand this properly.

On my '**players**' table, I need to list the following columns info:
*id, device_id and user_id* -

On my '**organizations**' table, I have a column named *name*.

I would like to list all "*device_id*" entries that are in relation with a given "*name*". This is what I tried as for the query:

```
select user_id, device_id from players 
join
select name from organizations where name like 'test';
```

The tricky part is that there are no columns with the same values on both tables. I mean, id or user_id exists in my '**organizations**' table but the values for one entry will be different from one table to another. Since there are no pieces of information that link the entries together, I suppose there's no way to do it but I'm not an expert as I said so maybe you guys have an idea. Thanks in advance.

Comment: add a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: Not knowing which columns/types are in each table is a good way to botch a join or other type of query.  Run the following two queries and then update your question with table structure for the two tables: `SELECT * FROM players LIMIT 1` and `SELECT * FROM organizations LIMIT 1`

Comment: What do you mean  with "I would like to list all "device_id" entries that are in relation with a given "name".   " if  you affirm that there are not relation between the tables??

Comment: we need to see the table structure and understand the relationship between the tables (either directly, or maybe there is a 3rd table involved if it's a many->many relationship). From your vague description it's hard to be certain. If there isn't a definable relationship between records in the two tables (which you appear to state when you say "there are no pieces of information that link the entries together") then your question does not make a lot of sense. An example of what the output should look like, and some sample input data, would also help a lot.

Comment: Do your table has a key for the table organizations? e.g. players.organization_id.

Comment: You are looking to perform a join, not a union just fyi.  What you have to do is determine a common element.  For instance, is a player a member of an organization, and if so, how do they connect.  Typically, you will have a 'primary' key which means that value uniquely identifies a row of data for each table.  Then, other tables can incorporate that primary key.  In this case, the Primary key for organization Rangers, might be 65, and then in the Players table, there might be a column named Organization_ID.  You join on those columns to correlate the tables.

Comment: @NateM. gotcha, I dont think I have what is called a primary key on that 'players' table, unfortunately. Thats what I was looking for at first (even though I didn't know how we call this) cause I was thinking, how the heck my query can make the link between the two tables if they don't have an identical value at all. I looked at id or user_id and the values from the row I selected are totally different on the two tables. Makes my task a little bit more complicated I guess

Comment: you have to look for the relationship diagram of the tables so you would know how players table can be associated to organizations table. you may need to have another table or tables for them to have the correct relationship. you said that both tables have user_id column but the data is different, how did you know that a device_id from player table is for that name in the organizations table even they have different user_id?

Comment: @FerdinandGaspar cause there are other columns in both tables like "name" and "serial" so I can associate the data with this. anyways, that was a dumb question. I'm really sorry for having asked this. I should have known that there's no way to achieve this if there are no foreign keys. thanks to all of you for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thanks to all of you for amazingly fast answers. There's like over 20 columns from the player's table. Doing

```
SELECT * FROM players LIMIT 1;
```

will result in a un-comprehensive bunch of characters. Since it was already complicated enough I decided not to do so.

@scaisEdge I thought it would have been possible by doing something like; select device_id from players where name like 'test' from organizations

Now I know it won't work cause there's no relation between the two tables. I wish I would have something like *players.organization_id* (I didn't program this stuff at first...) but it hasn't so, I will try to find another way.

@ADyson I hope there's a 3rd table that is in relation to '**organizations**' but then, I may encounter difficulties to make a relation with '**players**' again nah ? Is there a way to know which tables are in relation with the one I'm working on and if so, which column exactly makes that relation ?

Comment: "Is there a way to know which tables are in relation with the one I'm working on and if so, which column exactly makes that relation" Assuming the database has foreign keys defined properly, then it will be in the CREATE TABLE definition where the foreign key is defined. Usually a DB GUI for your DBMS will be able to generate such a statement. Depending on your DBMS there may be other scripts you can run which will discover and map relationships between tables for you. But it only works if the relationships were actually defined when the tables were created. If they weren't, you have to guess